# reading .txt file and making an array(java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, char

Im trying to read in a .txt file and make a multi dimensional array out of it. I dont understand why the i and j loops arent populating my array. Any pointers much appreciated....

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class arrayChallenge {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File input = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(input);
    int width=10, height=10;


    char [][] arrayMulti = new char[width][height];

    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        String x = scan1.next();
        char[] chars = x.toCharArray();
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
            arrayMulti[i][j]= chars[j]; 
        }
    }

        for(char [] xy: arrayMulti){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xy));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: just add some more print statements. Dont just print the final results, print the information that goes into individual steps as well. If you dont understand what your code is doing, then add means to *observe* more closely what it is doing!

Comment: hey thanks for the advice, i apologise for not fully understanding your point though..sorry...this is the class to read in the txt file and populate an array with it....its not really final results...as far as i see it ...by print statements ...sorry but each different system out only prints empty arrays:  []
[]
[]
[]
[]

Comment: What about that x that you read in. What about chars? That is what i mean: dont just print your multi array, print the *other* elements in your code. Or learn how to use a debugger so you can see the content of each variable, while stepping through execution.

Comment: thanks....ill try that....cheers

Comment: And for the record. A) learn about java naming conventions (class names go UpperCase for example), and use meaningful names. x, xy, ... all mean and tell nothing B) you should make your question a full [mcve]. What is missing? A clear description/example that shows what goes in, and what comes out. And what you would expect to come out.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your i and j loops as far as I can see. As long as the provided path to your file is correct and the file has the needed number of lines (>= your width variable) and each line has the needed number of characters (>= your height variable), it should work fine.

Comment: The problem is: a lot of guessing here. Actually we dont understand what the OP is asking, or what his problem is. From that point of view, your answer should rather be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @GhostCat. You're right, it should have been a comment. Sorry, I'm still new to the stackoverflow.